# Advanced Custom Fields Group values are empty but wrapping element still visible

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a Wordpress site using the `Advanced Custom Fields`. So now I only want to display these fields if they "exist" e.g. if they have content. I made this conditional statement:

```
$casemodule = get_field('case_page_instore');   

 if( $casemodule ) : ?>  
    <section class="block">
        <h2><?php echo $casemodule['case_header'] ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $casemodule['case_subtext'] ?></p>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So fa so good, If the fields `case_header` and `case_subtext` are empty, they will not be shown (obviously), but or some reason the `<section>`-tag is always visible, which is kind of strange since I followed the instructions on the [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/) page.

Can someone maybe tell me what is going on?

**UPDATE**

I tried to do the `var_dump($casemodule)` and the result was:

```
array(2) { ["case_header"]=> string(0) "" ["case_subtext"]=> string(0) }
```

but that didn't solve anything

Answer (score 1):

Just because `$casemodule['case_header']` and `$casemodule['case_subtext']` do not exist, it doesn't mean that `$casemodul` won't exist. It could be an array that contains other keys or it could be just an empty array, which will exist!

Try to check if `$casemodule['case_header']` and `$casemodule['case_subtext']` really exist:

```
$casemodule = get_field('case_page_instore');   

 if(isset($casemodule['case_header']) && isset($casemodule['case_subtext'])) : ?>  
    <section class="block">
        <h2><?php echo $casemodule['case_header'] ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $casemodule['case_subtext'] ?></p>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are unsure about a variable, always use `var_dump($variable)`, before you pass it to an if statement.

Comment: I tried but somehow it didnt work :-( Please check my updated question...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, the solution was:

```
if($casemodule['case_header'] && $casemodule['case_subtext']) : ?>
```

I simply removed the `isset` an voila! :-)

Thanks to Reza for the previous answer